# Integrating Keyyo API with asp.net webforms App

Tags: asp.net, webforms, voip

i am working right now on a small web app in which i have to integrate a soft phone(Keyyo API).But i don't know how to embed it in my app.
This is the url of an outgoing call :

```
 https://ssl.keyyo.com/makecall.html?ACCOUNT=<ligne keyyo>&CALLEE=<destination>& 
CALLEE_NAME=<nom appelé>
```

I don't know how to embed the url in a button click.

Comment: Do you need to redirect user to this page?

Comment: no , i don't want to redirect the user to this url.the url is used to make a phone call.
http://www.keyyo.com/fr/echanger/api_espace_developpeur.php 
you can check this url to more understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you had shared link to their document - keyyo.com/fr/echanger/api_espace_developpeur.php , i have looked there and found that it does following.

> With the API, you can use our services directly to the heart of your
>   information system. Keyyo provides an API based on HTTP requests GET
>   like to notify a client application for incoming or outgoing calls.
>   Another interface is also available to make an outgoing call from a
>   third party application.

That means, it is a `GET` request, you can use `WebClient` to make a `Get` request. Again, you told that this is needed on button click. To achieve this, you can write following in button click handler.

Note: Replace value of param1,param2,param3 with required values

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string api_url = string.Format("https://ssl.keyyo.com/makecall.html?ACCOUNT={0}&CALLEE={1}&CALLEE_NAME={2}", "param1","param2","param3");
    string output = string.Empty;
    using(System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient)
    {
        output = wc.DownloadString(api_url);
    }
    //<ligne keyyo>, <destination>, <nom appelé>, replace value of param1,param2,param3 with required values
}


<asp:Button ID="btnsub" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="btnsub_Click" />
```

Comment: sorry #Arindam but i get this error:"The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
can you help me.

Comment: There might be some issue with api - `ssl.keyyo.com`, make sure , you are setting correct params, and to verify, you can directly browse the url to check , if it succeed.

Comment: i browse directly the url and i get invalid LineID

Comment: this is the url i browse:https://ssl.keyyo.com/makecall.html?ACCOUNT=+33370996014&CALLEE=00170220985

Comment: I think originally you told there is 3 parameter,`CALLEE_NAME` - is the one, you are  missing . If you get this type of error such as `Invalid LineID`, you have to refer to their forum/document for more help. You can see that you are able to browse, and getting HTTP Status 200, so you are able to solve 1st step of your question. Now if you are getting error from API, you need to contact them. As per your original question, i have answered that, you need to use `WebClient` to invoke `Get` request to execute  API.

Comment: I would suggest, you need to put up one more question regarding this `Invalid LineID - keyyo API`. As this answers your question for `how to invoke api`.